# Change cell value based on other columns

Tags: vba, excel

I would love to do the following in the screenshot:

[image: excel screenshot]

- Column A: items that belongs to a category in Column C
- Column B: a logic test TRUE/FALSE
- Column C: categories (A&B)

The idea is to change "FALSE" to "TRUE" of all items within the same category if there is one item in the same category that is "TRUE". So in this case, since item 5 is "TRUE" and belongs to category B, other items within category B (i.e. item 2 and 3) would change to "TRUE".

The output should be the table on the right in the screenshot.

I'd assume there are two steps:

1. Identify the category that has a value of "TRUE"
2. Change all items within the category to "TRUE"

Comment: Nice! You have the steps to accomplish this!. So, do it!

Answer (score 0):

Just use [COUNTIFS](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842) combined with an IF.

My data looks like this:

[image]

In column H my formula is:

`=IF(COUNTIFS(C2:C9;I2;B2:B9;TRUE)=0;FALSE;TRUE)`

Adapt it to your needs

Comment: @yuuyuu If this answer helped, please, mark it as correct, so the question will be closed.

Answer (score -1):

[image][image]

Add formula in 4th and 5th column for 2nd dataset's 2nd column

Comment: You should type the formula used, not a screenshot

Comment: 4th :  =(B2,1,0)
5th : =C2&D2
7th : =IF(COUNTIF($E$2:$E$9,H2&1)=1,TRUE,FALSE)

Comment: IF WORKS THEN +1 PLZ

Answer (score -3):

Ok So I wouldn't do this with VBA. You could achieve what you would like with purely excel formulas.

1) You would need to have a Parameter section on your sheet for Item Number. please see the screenshot for a bit more of a visual

[image: Screenshot]

2) In my sheet that I created I used the following Formula to define the Logic Field which I copied across all the Logic Fields

```
    =IF(VLOOKUP($B$2,$A$5:$C$14,3,FALSE) = C5,TRUE, FALSE)
```

There are 2 parts to this Formula, the first is the VLOOKUP that evaluates Category that was entered in the parameters, then the IF that will compare the value returned from the VLOOKUP to the Category for the current line.

3) Now when you change the Item Parameter, all the logic fields will change to what they need to be

Comment: Can you mark it as the answer if it helped... thanks